# Dimple Filter for X Value

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I've been using a little d3 and am now exploring dimple. I am trying to create some pie charts. However, I want the `x-axis value` to be a subset of the actual values.

Here's what I have:

```
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);

//data
    var data = [{"Inst":"Two", "Finaid":"Grant", "Value":50},
                {"Inst":"Two","Finaid":"None", "Value":10},
                {"Inst":"Two","Finaid":"No", "Value": 30},
                {"Inst":"One", "Finaid":"Grant", "Value":20},
                {"Inst":"One","Finaid":"None", "Value":10},
                {"Inst":"One","Finaid":"No", "Value": 30}];

//basic chart
    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    console.log(data);
    chart.setBounds(50,20,460,360)
    chart.addCategoryAxis("y", "Inst")
    chart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Value");
    chart.addMeasureAxis("p", "Value");
    chart.addMeasureAxis("z", "Value");
    chart.addSeries("Finaid", dimple.plot.pie);
    chart.addLegend(600,20,90,300, "left");
    chart.draw();
```

So this works, but I want the `x-axis value` to only be the value of `"Finaid":"Grant"` something like `chart.addMeasureAxis("x", {"Finaid":"Grant"}.Value);`... although I realize that actual code does nothing.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you only want the data objects to be included in the pie chart dataset if they have "Finaid" = "Grant"? I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: @ne8il yes, that's what i'm hoping to do

Answer (score 1):

Just filter it before plotting.  In fact, `dimple.js` even offers a [helpful function](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple#filterData) for just that.

```
var data = [{"Inst":"Two", "Finaid":"Grant", "Value":50},
            {"Inst":"Two","Finaid":"None", "Value":10},
            {"Inst":"Two","Finaid":"No", "Value": 30},
            {"Inst":"One", "Finaid":"Grant", "Value":20},
            {"Inst":"One","Finaid":"None", "Value":10},
            {"Inst":"One","Finaid":"No", "Value": 30}];

var filteredData = dimple.filterData(data, "Finaid", "Grant");

// now make chart
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, filteredData);
```

Comment: hmmm, but I still want the piecharts to show data for all three `Finaid` statuses... the filter would prohibit that, no?

Comment: @As3adTintin I don't understand what you are asking then.  Can you mock-up a picture and update your question?